# Angular input model conditionally reads from one property, writes to another

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a Person class where edits made to the person must be verified by an admin user.

Each attribute has an "approved" and "tmp" version. Sometimes the "tmp" version is not set:

```
person = {first:'Bob', firstTmp:'Robert', last:'Dobbs', lastTmp:undefined}
```

When displaying the person, I want to display the "tmp" value if it is set, otherwise display the "approved" value. When writing, I want to write to the "tmp" value (unless logged in as an admin).

Ideally, this would not require a lot of custom markup, nor writing cover methods for each property (there are around 100 of them). Something like this would be nice:

```
<input ng-model="person.first" 
       tmp-model="person.firstTmp" 
       bypass-tmp="session.user.isAdmin" />
```

When displaying the value, display the tmp value if it is defined. Otherwise display the approved value.

When writing the value, write to the tmp value, unless logged in as an admin. Admins write directly to the approved value.

What's a good clean way to implement this in Angular?

- Extend NgModelController somehow?
- Use a filter/directive on the input?
- Cover methods?
- Just do the writing server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to go through your options one by one:

> Extend NgModelController somehow?

I don't think this is a good idea. It won't be nice if something goes wrong and you don't know if you can even rely on something as basic as `ng-model`

> Just do the writing server-side?

This would seem like the easier way (if you already know or find it easy to manage it in the back end), although the interaction would need a new request to the server.

> Use a filter/directive on the input?

I believe this would be the best way to do it, as it is easy to understand what is going on by just taking a look at the markup. It's angular, you already know that some property like `tmp-model` is extending the markup.

> Cover methods?

This would also be easy to implement, and you would be implementing some sort of "business logic" as a validator in your cover method.

Given that I've extended a bit in my answer, I can give you an inline example of the last one.

```
<input  ng-model="person.firstTmp"
        ng-init="person.firstTmp = person.firstTmp || person.first"
        ng-change="updateProperty(person, 'first')" />
```

And on the controller, you could do something like:

```
$scope.updateProperty = function(person, propertyName) {
    // The temporary property has already been changed, update the original one.
    if($scope.session.user.isAdmin)
        person[propertyName] = person[propertyName + 'Tmp'];
}
```